# Failing to get a file in Google Apps Script using the Drive API

Tags: google-apps-script, google-drive-api

I have a google apps script (that I use in one of my spreadsheets). I'm used to calling the DriveApp service to handle files (list, create, move, etc), but I wanted to get the user that last modified a file. Looking it up in several places, I understood that the only way to achieve that is to import the Drive API SDK (the Advanced Drive Service) into the Google Apps script. I added it using the [official documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/advanced/drive). So, here is where I'm stuck. To simplify, look at the code below:

```
console.log(DriveApp.getFileById('1eMIUTEmpvzN5a3kK6PWbK4W8RCkbNOSxxxxxxxxxxx').getName())
console.log(Drive.Files.get('1eMIUTEmpvzN5a3kK6PWbK4W8RCkbNOSxxxxxxxxxxx').title)
```

The first one shows my file name just fine.
The second one fails with:

> GoogleJsonResponseException: API call to drive.files.get failed with
> error: File not found: 1eMIUTEmpvzN5a3kK6PWbK4W8RCkbNOSxxxxxxxxxxx
>
> (anonyme) @ List Files.gs:2

Any ideas why it wouldn't work?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From your script and your error of `File not found`, I thought that in your situation, the file might be put in the shared Drive. If my understanding is correct, such error occurs. On the other hand, when `DriveApp.getFileById` is used, the file in the shared Drive can be retrieved. So in your situation, how about the following modification?

#### From:

```
console.log(Drive.Files.get('1eMIUTEmpvzN5a3kK6PWbK4W8RCkbNOSxxxxxxxxxxx').title)
```

#### To:

```
console.log(Drive.Files.get('1eMIUTEmpvzN5a3kK6PWbK4W8RCkbNOSxxxxxxxxxxx', {supportsAllDrives: true}).title)
```

#### Reference:

- [Files: get](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v2/reference/files/get)

Comment: You're a genius. That was it. I may be blind but I don't find that second argument in the get() method in the Google's reference (the link you posted, that I had already seen by the way). Anyways, thanks

Comment: @Adriano_Pinaffo Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. About `supportsAllDrives`, you can see the explanation at the official document. [Ref](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v2/reference/files/get) And, when you want to know the arguments of `Drive.get()`, for example, how about using the auto-completion of the script editor? In that case, you can see `get(fileId: string, optionalArgs: Object)`. By this, you can see the 2nd argument of `optionalArgs` which is [Parameters](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v2/reference/files/get#parameters).

Comment: Right... I had seen the context menu with "optionalArgs", and I had seen the Parameters list in the Reference... but I had never connected the dots. In my mind the Parameters in the reference were to be used in a GET http request as a querystring like `https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v2/files/fileId?supportsAllDrives=true`. It had not occurred to me that what the "Drive Advanced Service" in Google Apps is a client to allow you to interact with the Drive API the same way you would do from another app written in python for example. Thanks a lot

Comment: @Adriano_Pinaffo Thank you for replying. It seems that in `Drive.Files.get()` of Drive API at Advanced Google services, the query parameter is used as the JSON object like `{supportsAllDrives: true}` as the 2nd argument. For example, at other method, `Drive.Files.list(optionalArgs)` had an argument of `optionalArgs`. In this case, the query parameter is used to `optionalArgs` as JSON object. It seems that this is the current specification at Google side.